# How Can I get return value from function in object

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation, ecmascript-5

i want to get return value from function in object

it can call function in object but i cant get return value

how am i supposed to do

```
const depthCheck = state => {
  let index = state.index === undefined ? null : state.index;
  if (index !== null) {
    depthCheck(state.routes[index]);
  } else {
    console.log(state);
    return state;
  }
};

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabNavigator,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => (
      //call function but i cant get return value from console
      console.log(depthCheck(navigation.state))
    ),
  },
);
```

Comment: You don't return anything from your first branch.

Comment: but it call log in else
what am i wrong?

Comment: Let's say control went into this ```if (index !== null) {
    depthCheck(state.routes[index]);
  } ``` then there is no return stmt here..so you are not getting the return value.May be do like this ```if(){const value=depthCheck(); return value}```

Comment: Add "return depthCheck(state.routes[index]);", instead of the current one.

Comment: Oh my goodness~! Thank you, guys.  i appreciate it. I will try this tomorrow